# How to alter the gas stipend with high-level delegate call?

Tags: solidity, gas, delegatecall

When using the DELEGATECALL opcode via assembly, we can pass a specific amount of gas:

```
let result := delegatecall(gas(), implementation, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
```

But the high-level DELEGATECALL does not have such argument:

```
(bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.delegatecall(data);
```

How can we alter the gas stipend that we give to the delegated contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the gas using the gas modifier (in brackets) before the function args, e.g.:

```
(bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.delegatecall{ gas: 10000 }(data);
```

The modifiers are documented here:

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/types.html#address

Comment: Nice! I found them mentioned in [External Function Calls](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/control-structures.html#external-function-calls) as well.