# What happens when you pass more gas than what is available?

Tags: solidity, gas, contract-invocation, gas-limit

When making a contract call in Solidity, the gas stipend can be [altered](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/108093/24693) with the following [special options](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/control-structures.html#external-function-calls):

> {value: WEI_VALUE, gas: GAS_VALUE}

What happens when the `GAS_VALUE` is bigger than what is available? (i.e. bigger than the value returned by [gasleft](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=gasleft#block-and-transaction-properties))